# Proof that Rel is a Category

Tags: category-theory

The Awodey book about Category Theory gives this definition for Rel:

> The objects of $\text{Rel}$ are sets, and an arrow $A → B$ is a
>   relation from $A$ to $B$, that is, a subset $R ⊆ A×B$.
>
> The equality relation $ \{ \langle a, a\rangle ∈ A×A\;|\; a ∈ A\}$ is the identity
>   arrow on a set $A$.
>
> Composition in $\text{Rel}$ is to be given by: $$ S ◦ R = \{\langle a, c \rangle ∈ A × C \; |\; ∃b \;(  \langle a, b\rangle ∈ R \; \text{ and }\; \langle b, c\rangle ∈ S) \}$$
>
> for $R ⊆ A × B$ and $S ⊆ B × C$.

How can I actually prove that Rel is a category?

I'm not really into categories yet but this seem quite obvious since I know a category must have objects (that are the sets, in this case), arrows (relations), identity function (equality relation) and composition of functions (that is the association of relations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've quoted is a definition of all the data needed to have a category: objects, morphisms, identity morphisms, and composition operation.  To verify you have a category you then just have to check that this data satisfies the axioms for a category: that the identity morphisms are actually identities for the composition operation, and that composition is associative.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question was posted quite some time ago I feel like this exercise is very useful for anyone getting into category theory, which is why I provided a solution.

As Eric said, to show that $\mathbf{Rel}$ is a category we need to show that the identity arrows satisfy the identity law and the composition satisfies the associativity law.

Let $f: A \to B$ be a subset $f \subseteq A \times B$, $g: B \to C$ be subset $g \subseteq B \times C$, and $h: C \to D$ be a subset $h \subseteq C \times D$.

To show that $f \circ 1_A = f$, we use the axiom of extensionality (for both are sets).
For the forward direction, let $(a, b) \in f \circ 1_A$. Then we see by definition that there exists some $p$ s.t. $(a, p) \in 1_A$ and $(p, b) \in f$. Since $(a, p) \in 1_A$ implies that $p=a$, we have that $(a, b) \in f$. For the backward direction, let $(a, b) \in f$. Moreover, since $(a, a) \in 1_A$, we have per definition that $(a, b) \in f \circ 1_A$. The argument that $1_B \circ f = f$ is similar.

For the associativity, we want to show that $(h \circ g) \circ f = h \circ (g \circ f)$. We know that
\begin{align*}
(a, d) \in (h \circ g) \circ f &\iff \exists b: (a, b) \in f, (b, d) \in (h \circ g) \\
&\iff \exists b, c: (a, b) \in f, (b, c) \in g, (c, d) \in h \\
&\iff \exists c: (a, c) \in (g \circ f), (c, d) \in h \\
&\iff (a, d) \in h \circ (g \circ f),
\end{align*}
which is what we wanted to show.